# Wordpress - 2 Taxonomies Filter

Tags: php, wordpress

im a little bit stuck here.

The Build Up, i have several Pages with 2 Taxonomies. Branch and Topics.
Every Taxonomie has several Keywords.

What i now need is. Give me everything from "Topics" but only with a certain keyword from the Taxonomie Branch.

I tried it like this, but this gives me all from Topcis, without any filtering from Branch.

```
$termArgs = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'page',
            'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'CAT_TOPIC',
                'field'    => 'slug'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'CAT_BRANCH',
                'terms'    => 'solarteur',
                'field'    => 'slug'
            ),
    ));

$topicTerms = get_terms($termArgs);
```

**Update:
I hade a mistake in my question. I dont need pages. I just need a list of every taxonomie from 'CAT_TOPIC', not empty, that also has a certain keyword from 'CAT_BRANCH'**

I tried it like these, but i still get a list of everything from TOPIC.

```
$termArgs = array(
      'taxonomy' => CAT_TOPIC,
  'hide_empty' => true,
'parent' => 0,
             'tax_query' => array(
           'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'CAT_BRANCH',
                'terms'    => array('solarteur'),
                'field'    => 'slug'
            )
)
    );
```

**Update 2**
I now found a solution. I first get all Pages. 
After that i use the page ID with get_the_terms.
Now i have a nice array, just with some duplicates in my case. Get rid of this and im done^^

Thank you @Picard

```
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];

    $termArgs = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => CAT_TOPIC,
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => get_terms( CAT_TOPIC, array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'fields' => 'ids')),
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => CAT_BRANCH,
                'terms'    => $filter,
                'field'    => 'slug'
            )
        )
    );

  $topicTerms = get_posts($termArgs);
    $topicslugs = array();  

  foreach($topicTerms as $topicTermKey => $topicTerm):
        $currentTerms = get_the_terms( $topicTerm->ID, CAT_TOPIC);
        $length = count($currentTerms);
        for($x = 0; $x < $length ; $x++){
            $topicslugs[] = array($currentTerms[$x] -> slug, $currentTerms[$x] -> name);
        }
  endforeach;

    //remove duplicates
    $topicslugs = array_unique($topicslugs, SORT_REGULAR);
    $topicslugs = array_filter($topicslugs);
    $topicslugs = array_values($topicslugs);
```

Comment: Updated my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$termArgs = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tax_query' => array(
           'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'CAT_TOPIC',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => get_terms( 'CAT_TOPIC', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'fields' => 'ids')),
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'CAT_BRANCH',
                'terms'    => array('solarteur'),
                'field'    => 'slug'
            )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But i think, i hade a mistake in my question. I dont need pages. I just need a list of every taxonomie from 'CAT_TOPIC', not empty, that also has a certain keyword from 'CAT_BRANCH'.

Comment: Updated my Question with an new Code Snippet that not working :-)

Comment: Taxonomies don't have other taxonomies assigned, but are assigned to posts in general. So you can check for posts, pages having those taxonomies.

Comment: Thank you Captain @Picard I posted my solution in my opening post. I had to "filter" the pages so i only get the taxonomies i needed. Have a nice day°